# Anonymous comments not saved in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-comments

For some reason I can no longer post a comment as an Anonymous user in my Drupal installation. I haven't tried in a while, so I'm not quite sure when this functionality was broken.

I have Services installed, and I can post anonymous comments using `comment.save`. I have altered the `Input Formats` if that could break something.

I have enabled both `post comments` and `access comments` on the anonymous user. The comments does not show up in the database. In fact, the native Drupal function `comment_save` isn't called when I try to comment as Anonymous (I check this by adding `print_r($edit);die();` at the top of the `comment_save` function in `comment.module`. Also I read something that not having a User with the UID 0 would break the Anonymous commenting, this user exists (obviously, since commenting through Services works)

I have tried out the `AntiSpam` module, and posted a comment as Anonymous that would get caught(and did) in the spamfilter, but this module is now disabled.

I'm really running out of ideas here, does anyone have any other suggestions on what to do? In the meanwhile I'm going to attempt to backtrack the code to figure out why `comment_save()` isn't being called.

Edit: Anonymous users also don't have to submit email and such to post, if that matters in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what you say, I suspect the problem is with some contributed code hooking on the comment form and modifying it in a way that makes it fail submission. This can be caused by a number of causes: a jQuery that adds fields to the form without regenerating the form-id on the server, an added or cusomised field that changes the callback to submit the form, etc...

I cannot know it for sure, but here's what I would do if I were you, in order to check what's up with your installation:

- **Make sure you disinstalled (and not only disabled) the modules you tried** and don't use anymore. Modules should never touch core tables, but who knows... It does not cost anything and it actually frees some of your DB.
- **Try disabling all contrib modules** and see if you can comment that way. If this is the case, activate the contrib modules one at a time until you find out which one is the culprit. Chances are you will already find a patch/workaround in the issue queue for that module on http://drupal.org. If you don't find a fix, I would investigate (xdebug or manual tracking) the code, and I would pay special attention to all implementations of [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6) and [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6).
- If even disabling all contrib modules doesn't help (which I would be very astonished of), **try updating the core with a fresh installation** if you consider as a possibility that your cat walked on the keyboard while you had a core file opened, or [you live with Gordon Brown's family](http://www.madeformums.com/its-amazing/gordon-browns-toddler-son-tweets-on-wifes-twitter-page/4437.html).
- Failing that, the only alternatives coming to my mind are much more esoteric, such DB failure, a greasemonkey script on your browser interfering with commenting and similar unlikely possibilities.

HTH!

Comment: I searched for the suggested functions, and tried disabling the ones that implemented the function one by one, and now it's working again, the culprit in this case was `input_format_permissions`. I'm pretty new to Drupal, so I also thank you for the Drupal-specific debug checklist. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this once by resetting the permissions table (http://drupal.org/node/64114), but I would do a proper backup and keep the permissions page open in a tab, just in case.